# validation not fired unless you type

Tags: wpf, validation

I have three textbox in a WPF window with UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus". 
I have also a validation class (:ValidationRule) that return false or true based on my condition, and to keep it so simple: the condition is to check if the string is empty or not.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TestBox">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding ElementName="This" Path="test" 
         UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:IPv4ValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
<TextBlock Margin="2" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" 
       Text="{Binding ElementName=TestBox, 
                      Path=(Validation.Errors),
                      Converter={StaticResource eToMConverter}}" />
```

the problem is:
if you run the application, and you go through textboxs, no error will be shown on lost focus. I put a button to fire the validation in code, and no error is shown.

**ONLY if you type in the textbox, and then clear it, the validation will work.**

how can I solve this? because in this case, I cannot confirm if someone leave a textbox empty unless he type in and then delete.

Answer (score 0):

Reading on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx#data_validation), you can find that:

> Validation usually occurs when the value of a target is transferred to
>   the binding source property.

So your validation rule will not be evaluated without typing a key, unless you update the source.
You can do it in you code behind. Supposing that `MainWindow` is your window, you need to add a Loaded event handler:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BindingExpression bindingExpression = TestBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
}
```

As you can see, the handler's code updates the source, therefore the `ValidationRule` is evaluated.